# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion

How do we promote our site?

Comment: Yes, I shamelessly cribbed this from the "7 Essentials", but I wanted to get it up here so I could throw out my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Have somebody design labels that have the URL on them.

Answer (score 2):

I think that asking the hosts of homebrewing-related podcasts to mention the site might be worthwhile.  Basic Brewing is a great resource for brewers, and I think James would agree that  this site would be useful to his audience.

Comment: As mentioned in the "7 Essentials" it would be nice (actually, more important perhaps) to not only get them to mention the site, but to become a user as well.  Also, getting well known contest winners and micro-brewery owners as users would help also.  I have seen threads on SO where people /freak out/ because someone who wrote a popular library answered a question.  It'd be fun, and attract users, if that stuff happened here.

Answer (score 2):

I think targeting homebrew clubs would serve to get a very high response rate. I sent an email to my homebrew clubs email list, but I think I probably should have waited (and will resend) when we are in public beta.

Homebrew contests also seems like a high value target, though they are usually closely related to the clubs means you might just want to start with them.

Answer (score 2):

We have an auto-tweeting account set up from Brew Advice. It's currently tweeting updates from the new SE site via RSS feed.

http://twitter.com/brewadvice

We can update the settings or do whatever. Check it out.

Comment: great idea, I'll follow this, and retweet the ones I find really interesting.

Comment: The integration seems to be broken now, I see only old updates from 2012 !

Answer (score 1):

How about getting cards printed up with the URL and mission of the site and seeing if our LHBSs will put them out on the counter?

Comment: In that case, what is our mission?

Comment: Time to grab another of those 7 essential questions: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/18/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site

Answer (score 1):

We should notify all the homebrew magazines once the site goes live and see if they'll mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone here have some influence in the AHA? It would be great if we could get some notice/mention from them...