# Driving Traffic to this Site

Tags: discussion, users

I really like this site.  I am a web developer and I have found a TON of helpful resources on SO.  I know that home brewers are a much smaller market than programmers, but there are plenty of great pages out there dedicated to home brewing.

I saw on Area 51, that the average questions per day is only 1.9.  I suspect that by growing the user base, we will find that this concept can greatly serve the home brewing community.

What is being done to drive traffic at the time?  I would hate this site to become an archive somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it kinda already *is* an archive... Right here. Nothing wrong with that, as long as there are folks around to maintain the information in the archive.

That said... If folks are to hang around, they kinda need something to keep 'em interested. I'd recommend the following:

- **Don't make this your only homebrew site.** Hang around other forums; keep an ear out for what's happening in the field. If folks ask questions that have answers here, point that out to 'em; if they ask questions that *don't* have answers here, feel free to bring up the topic yourself - and if it gets a good answer, then point that out too.
- **Don't hesitate to post questions you're researching yourself.** One of the downsides of homebrew compared to (say) programming is that it requires a fair bit of patience. Testing a new technique or ingredient might require weeks or months before you have any results; if you post about what you're doing, others may be able to save you some time by sharing their own experience... And if not, you can report back and self-answer once your research is completed.
- **Do be patient** just as a lager might take a bit longer than an ale, some sites take longer to gain any real traction. If the topic interests you, hang around and do what you can to make the site work for you; don't stress over numbers.

#### See also:

- [How do we promote our site?](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-do-we-promote-our-site)
- [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)